# How to use SMTP.js in Vue.js - Import external scripts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, smtp, vuetify.js

Helle, I have a problem when using smtp.js and its external script in Vue.js. The problem isn mail.js, but I am not able to load the external Script into my vue-component. Then tried to solve this issue with vue-plugin-load-script for npm, but this doesn't works for me.
My Vue-Component:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="mt-10">
    <v-card max-width="400px" class="mx-auto mt-5">
      <v-card-title>If You've got a question?</v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle>Type it in below!</v-card-subtitle>
      <v-card-text>
          <v-text-field label="Your Name" v-model="name"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Your Email" type="email" v-model="email"></v-text-field>
          <v-textarea label="Your Message" counter="100" maxlength="100" auto-grow outlined v-model="message"></v-textarea>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn class="mx-auto mb-4 success" @click="sendEmail">Send Message</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>    
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Contact',
    data: () => ({
        email: "",
        message: "",
        name: "",

    }),
    methods: {
      sendEmail(){
        this.$loadScript("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js")
        .then(Email => {                                         //this Promise return nothing!!!
            Email.send({
                SecureToken : "3df7ff95-181c-4f27-9e94-ee2cfc280818",
                To : 'mail@example.com',
                From : this.email,
                Subject : this.name,
                Body : this.message,
            }).then(
                message => alert(message)
            );
        })
        .catch(() => {
        // Failed to fetch script
        });

        },
    },

}
</script>
```

The vue-plugin-load-script is imported in main.js like this:

```
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);
```

I hope you can help me solving this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Replace `.then(Email =>` with `.then(() =>`. and `Email.send` with `window.Email && window.Email.send`. The linked script attaches to the global window scope, and as you can see in the vue-plugin-load-script [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-load-script), the Vue plugin doesn't know what the script exports, and doesn't pass it as a parameter to the Promise.then. Also, you're not importing it "*in the Vue component*", it will be globally available on the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response. It works perfect. I had no idea, how to load a script like in a normal index.html in Vue. But thanks to your answer I solved my problem.